# Problem when adding to an ArrayList its remplace all the previous data

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm trying to read files (81 files) of Double, and put every file (16 double/file) them on a Double[], after that i creat an objet DataObject(Double[], int Class), and i want to add every instance of DataObject that i create to my ArrayList, but at the end, i have 81 SAME elements on my ArrayList, which is the data on the last file i read, need help.
thanks.`public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedReader reader;

```
    while (x <= 9){
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RF\\src\\E34\\s0"+x+"n00"+y+".E34"));
            String line= reader.readLine();       
            while(line !=null){
                try{
                    d[i] = Double.valueOf(line);
                    System.out.println(d[i] + " is a double.");
                    i++;  
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.err.println("Not Double ' "+line+" '");
                }
                line=reader.readLine(); 
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
        // AJOUT DE L'OBJET**************************************************************************
        obj = new DataObject(d, x);
        list.add(obj);
        System.out.println("objet ajouté");
        // REINITIALISATION du tableau d **********************************************************
        i = 0;
        y++;
        // CONDITION SUR LES FICHIER A LIRE***********************************************************
        if(y == 10){
            x++; y = 1;
        }
    }
    // LECTURE DES DONNEE *****************************************************************
    for(int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++){
        System.out.println(list.get(n).toStringObj());
    }`
```

And the class DataObject
`public class DataObject {
private double[] data;
private int classCode;

```
public DataObject(double[] data, int classCode) {
   //assert data.length == 100; //maximum array length of 100
   this.data = data;
   this.classCode = classCode;
}

public String toStringObj() {
       return "Class Code: " + classCode + " Data :" + Arrays.toString(data) + "\n"; //outputs readable
}

public double[] getData() {
       return data;
}

public int getClassCode() {
       return classCode;
}
```

}`

and this is the result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hULx.jpg)

81 line of the same data, but the ClassCode are not remplace by 9 everywhere.

Comment: Where are `d` and `x` used in the `main` method defined?

Comment: public static int k = 1,i=0, x = 1, y = 1, n=0;
 public static double[] d = new double[16];

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, i found the solution, when calling DataObject `obj = new DataObject(d, x);` he is always calling with the same `d`, thats why i have the same result, i tried with `obj = new DataObject(d.clone(), x);` and it works.